# Super Bowl Math Problem

Tags: probability, optimization

A lot of us buy Super Bowl boxes this time of year. Here is my question. Suppose that we have the usual 10 by 10 grid of Super Bowl boxes where the coordinates labels for the horizontal and vertical portions of the grid are random numbers from 0 to 9. At the end of each quarter the person who has the winning box is payed out 25% of the pot. Let $X$ be the return on your bet. Assuming you can't buy more than 20 boxes what is the optimal strategy to maximize $E(X)$.

Comment: "Super Bowl Boxes"? Oh, dear....and what in the world is that, anyway?

Comment: If I get that right, all bets are paid out, so on average you get what you paid, $E(X)=0$.

Comment: The expected payoff is always (at most) $0$, but you can influence the distribution of the payoff (i.e., you can influence for example the standard deviation).

Comment: For the benefit of people outside the USA, I will explain "Super Bowl boxes". This means that you pay a fee $f$ to select an ordered pair $\langle h, v\rangle$. Then if the American football annual championship game terminates with the two teams having scored $H$ and $V$ points respectively, you win $(1-r)\cdot 100\cdot f$ if and only if $H\equiv h\pmod{10}$ and $V\equiv v\pmod{10}$, where $0\le r\lt 1$ is a house "rake" constant. Often the coworkers in an office will divide up the 100 ordered pairs, at random or otherwise, and $r=0$.

Comment: In the example above, there is a variation: $25f$ is paid at the end of each *quarter* of the game to the player whose $\langle h,v\rangle$ matches the total score at the end of the quarter. The "optimal" strategy involves picking the correct pairs $\langle h,v\rangle$ with the greatest expected payoff. The expectations are not the same for each pair, because of the peculiarities of scoring in American football.  For example, $\langle 0,0\rangle$ is clearly a good pick because the game starts with $H=0, V=0$.